# Cannot create react element from string

Tags: reactjs

I have a factory where I want to spawn react components. For now I have `Load` and `Migrate`. Passing the imported name directly works fine:

```
...

return React.createElement(Migrate, {
    node: node,
    diagramEngine: diagramEngine
});
```

But I would like to insert the name dynamically.

```
...    

var ElementToCreate = node.state.manipulator.name;

return React.createElement(ElementToCreate, {
    node: node,
    diagramEngine: diagramEngine
});
```

But this blows up with error message:

> Warning: Unknown props `node`, `diagramEngine` on  tag.
>   Remove these props from the element

Passing raw strings "Migrate" or "Load" also fails. Following the tips [here](https://reactjs.org/warnings/unknown-prop.html) did not help me identify the issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass in a string as the first argument to `React.createElement`, it will be considered an HTML tag name, which isn't what you want.

Instead, use a registry to map from name to actual component class:

```
import Foo from './Foo';
import Bar from './Bar';
import Quux from './Quux';

const TYPE_REGISTRY = {
    // Using ES object literal shorthand to
    // avoid repeating the names
    Bar,
    Foo,
    Quux,
};

// ...

class ... {

    render() {
        // typeName would be one of "Bar", "Foo" or "Quux".
        const typeName = node.state.manipulator.name;
        const element = TYPE_REGISTRY[typeName];
        if(!element) {
            return <div>Invalid type name {typeName}</div>;
        }
        return React.createElement(element, {node, diagramEngine});
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great!

Answer (score 1):

See AKX answer. For sanity as I will have lots of imports, I also moved it all to its own file.

```
import Load from "./Load";
import Migrate from "./Migrate";
...

const AllManipulators = {
    Load,
    Migrate
    ...
};

export default AllManipulators;
```

Then

```
import AllManipulators from "./AllManipulators"
return React.createElement(AllManipulators[name], {
    node: node,
    diagramEngine: diagramEngine
});
```